# Downsides to storing extra information in document in OpenSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, opensearch

Let's say I have an index like this:

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "id":{"type":"text", "index":true},
    "name":{"type":"text", "index":false},
    "email":{"type":"text", "index":false}
  }
}
```

Then, I store documents like this:

```
{"id":"123", "name":"Foo Bar", "email":"foo@bar.baz"}
```

What are the downsides of storing data in a document that I'm not indexing, especially when it is small strings or primitives?

I assume actually indexing those columns can be expensive, similar to how you might not want to index every column in a relational database, but I'm not sure of the downsides when they're not indexed.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the information you're storing/indexing. What's your use case? How are you going to search for your documents (obviously neither by name nor by email)?

Comment: @Val i was just storing it in opensearch to populate a search results table, that way i dont have to fetch more data after doing the search. but im not sure if there is some massive downside to storing that extra data that isnt indexed.

Comment: There isn't... as long as your cluster supports it and performance is not impacted negatively. What this means is that you need to test :-)